# Ruby Conditional Test

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I can't make my code pass this test:

```
it "translates two words" do
    s = translate("eat pie")
    s.should == "eatay iepay"
  end
```

I don't see the flaw in my logic, though it may be very brute force and there may be a simpler way of passing the test:

```
def translate(string)
    string_array = string.split
    string_length = string_array.size
    i=0

    while i < string_length
        word = string_array[i]
        if word[0] == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
            word = word + "ay"
            string_array[i] = word

        elsif word[0] != ( "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" ) && word[1] != ( "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" )
            word_length = word.length-1
            word = word[2..word_length]+word[0]+word[1]+"ay"
            string_array[i] = word

        elsif word[0] != ( "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u" )
            word_length = word.length-1
            word = word[1..word_length]+word[0]+"ay"
            string_array[i] = word
        end

        i += 1
    end
    return string_array.join(" ")
end
```

Here's the test failure message:

Failures:

```
 1) #translate translates two words
     Failure/Error: s.should == "eatay iepay"
       expected: "eatay iepay"
            got: "ateay epiay" (using ==)
     # ./04_pig_latin/pig_latin_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The additional code checking other conditions are for other tests that I already passed. Basically, now I'm checking a string with two words.

Please let me know how I can make the code pass the test. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"` is evaluated to `"a"` because `"a"` is truth value. (not a `nil`, not a `false`):

```
irb(main):001:0> ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
=> "a"
irb(main):002:0> "a" == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
=> true
irb(main):003:0> "e" == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
=> false
```

How about using [`Array#include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) instead:

```
irb(main):001:0> %w{a e i o u}.include? "a"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> %w{a e i o u}.include? "e"
=> true
```

or using `=~` (regular expression match):

```
irb(main):007:0> "e" =~ /[aeiou]/
=> 0
```

Comment: `%{a e i o u}` should've been `%w{a e i o u}`, shouldn't it? `%{}` is an obscure way to create a string (including all space characters unlike `%w()`).

Comment: @cremno, Thank you for pointing that out. I fixed the code accordingly.